# Getting private bool property from method in Arduino library

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-yun

I'm creating my own library in arduino to controlling a pump.
The library is very simple:

---

**Pump.h**

```
#ifndef Pump_h
#define Pump_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class Pump
{
  public:
    Pump(int pin);
    void Open(void);
    void Close(void);
    boolean IsOpen(void);
  private:
    int _pin;
    bool _status;
};

#endif
```

---

**Pump.cpp**

---

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Pump.h"

Pump::Pump(int pin)
{
  pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pin,HIGH);
  _pin = pin;
  _status = false;
}

void Pump::Open(void)
{
  digitalWrite(_pin, LOW);
  _status = true;
}

void Pump::Close(void)
{
  digitalWrite(_pin, HIGH);
  _status = false;
}

boolean Pump::IsOpen(void)
{
  return _status;
}
```

---

**loop()**

---

```
#include <Pump.h>
#define PUMP1 Pump(9)

void loop() {
  BridgeClient client = server.accept(); // Get clients coming from server
  if (client) {  // There is a new request from client?
    Console.println("Client connected");
    process(client);  // Process request
    client.stop();    // Close connection and free resources.
  }
  Console.println(PUMP1.IsOpen());
  delay(50); // Poll every 50ms
}
```

The problem is that when I call the function IsOpen inside the loop() function of Arduino I get always false and the Pump is immediately turned off.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please show your `loop()`

Comment: I have edited the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PUMP1.IsOpen()` simply creates a temporary object of `Pump` class that is immediately destroyed.

You need to create an object of `Pump` that live throughout the execution of program. I am not familiar with Arduino call flow, but you could achieve this with some initialization/setup method or use singleton design or for this simple use case create a global object of `Pump` (which I normally don't educate people and is against using such design)

Comment: thanks, solved.
Just removed the #define and use instead Pump PUMP1(9);